# How to sort list with nested lists alphabetically by the name in the nested lists, then sort the nested list by highest value in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

I would like to know how I can sort a score list alphabetically by the name string in the nested lists, then sort the scores in the nested list by highest to lowest value:

For example:

```
list=[['a', 9, 3], ['we', 2], ['will', 2, 10], ['x', 4], ['z', 4]]
```

I have tried using `.sort()` and `sorted()` and a bit of `lambda`, but I do not understand it fully.

The expected output would be:

```
[['a', 9, 3],['we', 2],['will', 10, 2],['x',4],['z', 4]]
```

Comment: An example of your data and expected output (and what you've tried) would be good.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry this is my first attempt at asking a question

Comment: @williammahendran and the expected output would be? If you share your attempted code - someone will be able to correct/explain it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your case, you want to sort the inner lists without their first element. You can use the slice operator to get this sublist and also to replace it:

```
mylist=[['a', 9, 3], ['we', 2], ['will', 2, 10], ['x', 4], ['z', 4]]
for sublist in mylist:
    sublist[1:] = sorted(sublist[1:], reverse=True)
```

Note that it's better to not name your list `list` as it's also the name of the type.

Comment: For example: [['a',9,2],['z',10,4],['x',2,1]] to say [['z',10,4],['a',9,2],['x',2,1]]